Adding bloom in Blender 4.2
In previous versions of Blender, there was an option in the output properties to enable bloom. It seems that this was removed when it was updated to 4.2. Is there another way to allow bloom in Blender version 4.2? Perhaps in the texture system?

You need to use the Glare filter node in the Compositing setup, and choose the Bloom or Fog Glare option at the top:


Here's a detailed walkthrough, first hit on Google for "Bloom Blender 4.2":
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bqmmKpeQ_rw

Alternatively, there's a (currently) $3 extension named "Add Bloom Add-on" that adds an Add Bloom section to the render properties:
https://blendermarket.com/products/add-bloom-back
